# Having radio buttons reflect the model

Tags: elm

In [this example](http://elm-lang.org/examples/radio-buttons), the initial `fontSize` is `Medium`. This is reflected in the size of the font, but the medium radio button is not selected. Is there a way to make the radio button always reflect the current `fontSize`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ fieldset []
        [ radio "Small" (model.fontSize == Small) (SwitchTo Small)
        , radio "Medium"(model.fontSize == Medium)  (SwitchTo Medium)
        , radio "Large" (model.fontSize == Large) (SwitchTo Large)
        ]
    , Markdown.toHtml [ sizeToStyle model.fontSize ] model.content
    ]


radio : String -> Bool > msg -> Html msg
radio value isChecked msg =
  label
    [ style [("padding", "20px")]
    ]
    [ input [ type_ "radio", name "font-size", onInput msg, checked isChecked ] []
    , text value
    ]
```

Note that I changed onClick to onInput, which I think is better practise for form selections.

As an aside, I tend to put the msg parameter at the beginning of the type signature as that's the least likely to be part of a pipeline of functions:

```
radio : msg -> Bool -> String -> Html msg
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the code in question:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ fieldset []
        [ radio "Small" (SwitchTo Small)
        , radio "Medium" (SwitchTo Medium)
        , radio "Large" (SwitchTo Large)
        ]
    , Markdown.toHtml [ sizeToStyle model.fontSize ] model.content
    ]


radio : String -> msg -> Html msg
radio value msg =
  label
    [ style [("padding", "20px")]
    ]
    [ input [ type_ "radio", name "font-size", onClick msg ] []
    , text value
    ]
```

And this is the line used to render a radio input:

```
input [ type_ "radio", name "font-size", onClick msg ] []
```

There’s a `checked` attribute for radios ([see the docs](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html-Attributes)), so it looks you could add that depending on the current font size? Something like:

```
radio : String -> Bool -> msg -> Html msg
radio value isChecked msg =
  label
    [ style [("padding", "20px")]
    ]
    [ input [ type_ "radio", name "font-size", checked isChecked, onClick msg ] []
    , text value
    ]
```

…and then set the `isChecked` argument according to the model in the `view` function.

Comment: Any reason why the official [guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/v/a4b34b537117aa92fd8eba28cbdb3c93454f28db/reuse/radio_buttons.html) does not talk about to toggle the set? It is quite frustrating to see that the guide is not complete...